# uninitialized constant Spec::Rails (NameError) when running spec command

Tags: rspec

I get the following error when trying to run a spec command on a model test.

The command is:

```
C:\Rspec Test\spec\models>spec bank_account_spec.rb
```

The error is :

> c:/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-rails-1.3.0/lib/spec/rails/matchers/
>   ar_be_valid.rb:2: uninitialized constant Spec::Rails (NameError)
>           from c:/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-rails-1.3.0/lib/spec/ra
>   ils/matchers/ar_be_valid.rb:31:in `require'
>           from c:/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31
>   :in`require'
>           from C:/Rspec Test/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/depende
>   ncies.rb:158:in `require'
>           from c:/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-rails-1.3.0/lib/spec/ra
>   ils/matchers.rb:2
>           from c:/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-rails-1.3.0/lib/spec/ra
>   ils/matchers.rb:31:in`require'
>           from c:/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31
>   :in `require'
>           from C:/Rspec Test/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/depende
>   ncies.rb:158:in`require'
>           from c:/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-rails-1.3.0/lib/spec/ra
>   ils.rb:15
>            ... 13 levels...
>           from C:/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/bin/spec:5
>           from C:/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/bin/spec:22:in `l
>   oad'
>           from c:/jruby-1.5.0/bin/spec:22

I actually tried changing version to 1.3.0 in the `C:\jruby-1.5.0\bin\spec` file but it results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This error suggests that the rspec framework is not getting loaded in the environment where this code is executing.

```
uninitialized constant Spec::Rails (NameError)
```

- For rspec with rails 2.x, then follow install steps https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/rails
- For rspec with rails 3.x, follow install steps https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

Rails 3 requires rspec 2 . Development of rspec-rails-2 has moved to github.com/rspec/rspec-rails.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps any more, since the question is quite old, but I just found it through google, so this might help someone.

I too had declared my matcher using `Spec::Matchers.define`, out of some example found online. Apparently, this is outdated, once I changed the definition to `RSpec::Matchers.define` (mind the 'R' in 'RSpec'), things worked fine again.

I only got the error in debug mode and I am not using JRuby, but this might still be worth a try, and it's more correct anyway.